# Ansible regrex_replace to modify file name through path(url)

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying to modify file name after fetching it from its path using basename in Ansible,
I was successfully able to remove extension from name, but unable to achieve next target

Path: **/bin/data/xyzzz_no_db_20.9.1-82.tgz**

**(i.e: xyzzz_no_db_20.9.1-82.tgz *=>* xyzzzz_no_db**_**20.9.1-82 => xyzzz_no_db:20.9.1-82.**(***Final outcome expected***)

Basically, need to replace last occurence of (_)(underscore) with (:)(coln), and tried same by using code mentioned below, their must be some modification required.

Thanks in Advance.

```
- name: Modify image name
  set_fact:
     imagename: " {{ latest_file.path | basename | regex_replace('.tgz', '') | regex_replace('/^[^_^_]*[0-9]/',':')}}"
```

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it worked as required.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may actually use a single regex for that:

```
(.*)_(.*)\.tgz$
```

Replace with `\1:\2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTU31B/1)

In the code,

```
- name: Modify image name
  set_fact:
     imagename: " {{ latest_file.path | basename | regex_replace('(.*)_(.*)\\.tgz$', '\\1:\\2') }}"
```

**Regex details**

- `(.*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore (not captured, we'll replace it with `:` in the replacement pattern)
- `(.*)` - Group 2 (`\2`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.tgz` - `.tgz` substring (note the `.` is escaped to match a literal `.` char)
- `$` - end of string.